# android malloc crash when using libc_malloc_debug_leak

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, malloc, native-code

I was trying to investigate my native memory usage on Android 6.0, but my app keeps crashing when trying to malloc some memory. The steps are as follows:

1. I dowlownded libc_malloc_debug_leak.so from CM rom for my phone(Nexus 5)
2. Set libc.debug.malloc 1.
3. restart my phone.
4. install my app.

on old android devices like `4.4`, this works perfectly, but when I do this on `Android 6.0`, my app keep crashing. I have no idea why this happened and how to find the answer. Can anyone help?

BTW, I am using `ndk-r9c`, I know the newest is `r11`, but It'll take lots of works to upgrade to `r11`, I'm not sure if this is the cause, I'll try it while looking for some one to answer my question. The dumped crash log is as follow:

```
Stack frame #00 pc 001e7abe  /data/app/com.myapp-1/lib/arm/libmylib_ol.so: Routine __gabixx::__default_terminate() at libgcc2.c:?

Stack frame #01 pc 001e7acf  /data/app/com.myapp-1/lib/arm/libmylib_ol.so: Routine __gabixx::__terminate(void (*)()) at libgcc2.c:?

Stack frame #02 pc 001e7b2b  /data/app/com.myapp-1/lib/arm/libmylib_ol.so: Routine std::terminate() at libgcc2.c:?

Stack frame #03 pc 001e729b  /data/app/com.myapp-1/lib/arm/libmylib_ol.so: Routine __cxxabiv1::call_terminate(_Unwind_Control_Block*) at libgcc2.c:?

Stack frame #04 pc 001e73f7  /data/app/com.myapp-1/lib/arm/libmylib_ol.so: Routine __cxxabiv1::scanEHTable(__cxxabiv1::ScanResultInternal&, int, bool, _Unwind_Control_Block*, _Unwind_Context*) at libgcc2.c:?

Stack frame #05 pc 001e7921  /data/app/com.myapp-1/lib/arm/libmylib_ol.so: Routine __gxx_personality_v0 at libgcc2.c:?

Stack frame #06 pc 00008a03  /system/lib/libc_malloc_debug_leak.so (_Unwind_Backtrace+130)

Stack frame #07 pc 000060ef  /system/lib/libc_malloc_debug_leak.so

Stack frame #08 pc 00006b69  /system/lib/libc_malloc_debug_leak.so (leak_malloc+84)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were only lucky that it worked before. You can't take an unofficial system library from one build and expect it to work on another. There's no enforcement that the library works in a way that's compatible across even patch releases of the same device.

FYI, we're working on making this feature (debug malloc) generally available to app developers, but it's not ready yet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After trying lots of methods, I upgrade my native library to ndk r11, and it is working.